# Android random exceptions on HTTP calls. Why?

Tags: android, http

I'm testing my app on 3 devices so far. One device LG Optimus from Sprint never throws exceptions on https calls (maybe once in a week)

Nexus S on T-Mobile almost every hour come up with something like this:

> Read error: ssl=0x3f4060: I/O error
>   during system call, Connection reset
>   by peer

Now I got tablet for testing (S7 slim) and it's connected via WiFi and I get errors like:

> SSL shutdown failed: I/O error during
>   system call, Broken pipe

Do you know why those happen and is there any way to avoid them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest by peer means the server is rejecting/losing your connection. The SSL failure is probably a direct result of the connection reset. My bet is that this happen when switching networks (wifi to 3G) in the middle of some long standing connection.

If possible create a connection, do any IO, and disconnect as quickly as possible. If you do need to handle long persistent connection be prepared to handle such exceptions and reconnect behind the scenes.

Comment: I create and reuse connection in my own Application class. I do handle those fine, I just wondered why. So, if I create connection every time instead of once then I should not see that?

Comment: @katit: probably, it all depends on how you are reusing connections. It's a good idea to reuse connections, especially SSL connections if possible, but if you have do, be careful with long lived connections (even ones in reserve). I don't know enough about your app to be sure but you can probably create a pool, use them, and then throw them away until the next batch of connections are needed.