# Unexpected IOException when I try to send a post through HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: android, post, httpclient, ioexception, httpsurlconnection

My Android code sends data all the time and it seems to be working until a totally unexpected IOException is thrown, freezing everything. I don't understand why I can send several post requests without problem until the Exception appears, almost randomly.  Here's my code:

```
public class HttpsClient {

private final static String TAG = "HttpsClient";

private final static String TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = "Token";

private final String urlString;

private SSLContext sslContext;

// application-specific HTTP header
private String TokenHeaderValue = null;



public HttpsClient(String host, String path) {
    // this.sslContext will be init'ed in open()
    this.urlString = "https://" + host + ":443/" + path;
}


public boolean open() {
    try {
        this.sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        this.sslContext.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "NoSuchAlgorithmException:");
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "KeyManagementException:");
    }

    return false;
}


public byte[] send(byte[] req) {

    Logger.d(TAG, "sending " + Utils.byteArrayToString(req) + " to " + this.urlString);

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(this.urlString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException:");
        return null;
    }
    HttpsURLConnection connection;
    try {
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "send IOException 1 " + ((null == e.getMessage()) ? e.getMessage() : ""));
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    try {
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    } catch (ProtocolException ignored) { }
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(this.sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    connection.setReadTimeout(3000);



    if ( this.TokenHeaderValue != null )
        connection.setRequestProperty(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, this.TokenHeaderValue);



    {
        final Map<String, List<String>> requestProps = connection.getRequestProperties();
        Logger.d(TAG, requestProps.size() + " Request header(s):");
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : requestProps.entrySet())
            for (String value : entry.getValue())
                Logger.d(TAG, " " + entry.getKey() + ": <" + value + ">");
    }

    try {
        // open up the output stream of the connection 
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); 

        // write out the data 
        output.write(req, 0, req.length);
        output.flush();


        Logger.i(TAG, "Response Code: " + connection.getResponseCode());
        Logger.i(TAG, "Response Message: " + connection.getResponseMessage()); 
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "SocketTimeoutException:" + ((null == e.getMessage()) ? e.getMessage() : ""));
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) { // FAILS HERE !!!!!!!
        Logger.e(TAG, "send IOException 2 " + ((null == e.getMessage()) ? e.getMessage() : ""));
        return null;
    }


    final Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaderFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
    Logger.d(TAG, responseHeaderFields.size() + " Response header(s):");
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : responseHeaderFields.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        if ( (null != key) && key.equals(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY) )
            this.TokenHeaderValue = entry.getValue().get(0);
        for (String value : entry.getValue())
            Logger.d(TAG, " " + key + ": <" + value + ">");
    }


    // read response
    ArrayList<Byte> response = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    try {
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 

        // read in each character until end-of-stream is detected
        for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) {
            response.add((byte) c);
        }
        Logger.w(TAG, "Https connection is " + connection);
        connection.disconnect();
        Logger.w(TAG, "Https connection is " + connection);
        input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "send IOException 3 " + ((null == e.getMessage()) ? e.getMessage() : ""));
        return null;
    }

    if ( 0 == response.size() ) {
        Logger.w(TAG, "response is null");

        return null;
    }

    // else

    byte[] result = new byte[response.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        result[i] = response.get(i).byteValue();

    Logger.i(TAG, "Response payload: " + Utils.byteArrayToString(result));



    return result;          
}
}
```

I repeat: code works 'til after many post send, then crashes 'cause of an IO Exception. Moreover, server is fine, there's something wrong in my code.

Here's the entire error stack trace:

```
send IOException 2 

0: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read_byte(Native Method)

1: org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:783)

2: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readLine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:671)

3: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.readResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:699)

4: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getFromNetwork(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1088)

5: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1041)

6: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:736)

7: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:146)

8: com.bitstorms.gui.channels.HttpsClient.send(HttpsClient.java:117)

9: com.bitstorms.gui.apps.Application$MyRunnable.run(Application.java:81)

10: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suspicious point is that you never properly release streams. For instance, you create `DataOutputStream output`, use it, but never close. Try to change the code that uses `finally` to close the stream:

```
DataOutputStream output = null;
try {
    output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    ...
} catch (...) {
    ...
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
         try {
             output.close();
         } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

The same should be done with `DataInputStream input` and the `connection` itself (it should be guaranteedly closed in some global `finally` section).

Comment: I tried to put the finally section you're talking about to close streams (input also) but nothing, code's behaviour is the same... I don't understand...

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: Then I am out of ideas. Could you post the error stacktrace (you can edit your initial post and append it with the stacktrace). Probably it could give some ideas.

Comment: Just edited my question. Provided the entire stack trace, did you see it?

Comment: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy tablet to try this client, with Android 3.2, are there some known bug in that release about httpsurlconnection?

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: Just checked the stack trace. As you see it happens at the native method `NativeCrypto.SSL_read_byte()`. I have no idea why it fails. Its API doc just says it may throw the `IOException`, but without any explanation of possible reason(s).

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: I am not aware of any known bugs for this.

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: I can propose to think about 2 ideas on how to workaround this. 1st can be related to `SSLContext`. Do you really need to create/init it explicitly? Shouldn't it be handled automatically even if you don't create/init it explicitly? Even if you really need to create/init it explicitly, then try not to reuse the instance (make sure you always call `open()` before `send(byte[] req)`.

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: 2nd idea is to switch from `HttpsURLConnection` to `HttpClient`. BTW, despite Google says "use HttpURLConnection, because we fixed it (in 2.2 it had some issues) and optimized", I still prefer `HttpClient` because it is more OOP'ish. :) What I dislike is `URL.openConnection()` signature, because URL is just a URL (a little piece of info, a link) it should not open a connection!

Comment: @Ahrimed I did what you say, HttpClient class is surely more OOP'ish, you're right, but the application throws the same exception with one more information on the error stack trace that says : 
 11-25 17:15:07.570: E/HttpsClient(3525): Read error: ssl=0x466590: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer. Other messages on the stack trace are the same. What could it be?

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: Sorry, I have no idea.. Looks like similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478814/android-query-random-sslexceptions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319977/android-random-exceptions-on-http-calls-why.

Comment: I solved my problem: it was an error thrown by server that doesn't have relationship with my http connection, which was fine. However I have written a different code to use http connection, following ahrimed suggestion: I used HttpClient 'cause it's more OOP'ish and more clean.

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: I think you should not accept my answer as a solution, because others may think it is a solution while actually it is not! However you can just upvote my answer since it provided you some help.

Comment: According to Stack Overflow, I have not the reptutation to upvote your answer yet, sorry. But it was very useful, and I read your answers everywhere on Stack Overflow, you're great ^^

Comment: @FrancescoNovecentoNicolosi: Thanks! :) However once you get the required reputation, please do that.